# How to limit amount of numbers after comma in metapost?

Tags: metapost, floating-point

I would like to limit floating point numbers inside a label:

```
beginfig(1)
   for i=1 upto 5:
      label.bot(textext("$" & (decimal (-0.8*i)) & "$"), (-0.8*i, -0.2));
endfig;
end;
```

Currently it shows 5 numbers after comma. I need 2.

Comment: do you need rounding or simply truncated to 2 digits ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @jfbu truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a MetaPost macro to select the right substring:

```
vardef tdecimal(expr num, d) :=
  save numS; string numS; numS = decimal(num);
  save j; j := length numS;
  for k = 0 upto length numS - 1:
    if "." == substring (k,k+1) of numS: j:=k; fi
  endfor
  for k = j + 1 upto j + d:
    if "0" <> substring (k,k+1) of numS: j:=k+1; fi
  endfor
  substring (0,j) of numS
enddef;
```

Then you can use e.g. `tdecimal(1.234567, 2)` to get `1.23` or `tdecimal(1.234567, 3)` to get `1.234`.

An easier alternative would be to separately get the string representation of the integral and the decimal part, but this leads to some rounding problems in MetaPost.
Anyway, if you want to try it, the code would be

```
vardef twodecimal(expr num) :=
  if num < 0:
    "-" & decimal(floor(-num)) & "." & substring (1,3) of decimal(floor((-num-floor(-num)+1)*100))
  else:
    decimal(floor(num)) & "." & substring (1,3) of decimal(floor((num-floor(num)+1)*100))
  fi
enddef;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `\usepackage{xintfrac}` to preamble (prologue? I don't remember metapost terminology) and use

```
label.bot(textext("$\xintRound{2}{" & (decimal (-0.8*i)) & "}$"), (-0.8*i, -0.2))
```

---

Well I did your job and I opened up MetaPost manual. I don't know what is your "textext", which must be provided by some additional macros.

```
input TEX;

TEXPRE("\input xintfrac.sty\relax");

beginfig(1);
pickup pencircle scaled 1pt;
draw (0,0);
numeric i;
i := 1.236;
label.bot(TEX("$\xintTrunc{2}{" & (decimal (-0.8*i)) & "}$"), (-0.8*i, -0.2))
endfig;

end
```

When acted upon by `mpost` produces a correct EPS file. I used `\xintTrunc` as you want truncation. That could be done with no package at all (truncation is easier than rounding.)

I searched MetaPost manual for all occurences of "decimal" and did not see how to do the truncation before hand, but that must be possible because among the references I see "decNumber ANSI C implementation of general decimal arithmetic".

Comment: gives error `Command failed: latex mpeQcIXw.tex; see mpxerr.log
`

Comment: also:
`! ! Unable to read mpx file.
l.7 latexmp_picture[1]:= btex
                              $\xintround{2}{-0.8}$ etex ;
`

Comment: second part of my answer was added after above comments by OP.

Comment: `textext`is a macro shipped with Metafun, which is shipped with ConTeXt.

Comment: @sztruks thanks, the OP did not add any tag to this effect, and I don't have context installed at my locale. From one comment above I see "latex" is called, then clearly one must use `\usepackage{xintfrac}` as I said in my initial posting, and not `\input xintfrac.sty\relax` which is for `pdftex`,  or any `(whatever)etex`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of "tdecimal". Any improvement is welcome.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

vardef tdecimal(expr num, d) :=
   save numS, k, j, jj, ep_, dp_ ;
   numeric k, j, jj, ip_, dp_ ;
   string numS ;
   numS = decimal(num) ;

   if (d <= 0) :
      decimal(round(num))
   else :
      if (d <= 14) :
         if (num >= 0) :
            j := 1 ;
         else :
            j := -1 ;
         fi ;
         ip_ := abs(floor(num)) ;
         dp_ := round((abs(num) - ip_)*(10**d))/((10**d)-0.1) ;   % -0.1 : Pb d'arrondi de MP
         numS := decimal(j*(ip_ + dp_)) ;
      fi ;
%     Position of '.'
      j := -1 ;
      jj := length(numS) ;
      k := 0 ;
      forever: exitunless (k <= jj - 1) ;
         if "." = substring (k, k+1) of numS :
            j := k ;   % position of '.'
            k := jj ;  % to exit loop
         fi ;
         k := k + 1 ;
      endfor
      if j < 0 :
         numS := numS & "." ;
         j := jj ;
      fi ;
      for k = j + 1 upto j + d :
         if (substring (k, k+1) of numS) = "" :
            numS := numS & "0" ;
         fi ;
      endfor ;
      substring (0, j+d+1) of numS
   fi
enddef ;


%show tdecimal(3.141592, 4) ;
%show tdecimal(-3.141592, 4) ;
```